# Receiving apparent permissions error on SQL Server Agent job run as proxy user - how to find source of issue?

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to set up a process to reload a third-party database file onto our test server, for the purposes of creating an output CSV file to review.  This process, from reload to file output, is being built in SSIS.  It is expected to be run daily, so I am attempting to set it up as an SQL Server Agent job.

As the process will be writing out a file, I have been requested to use a specific Windows-side service user that was created for this project and given access to the intended output directory.

One of my coworkers created a specific credential for this service user.  I then set up a proxy for it in SSMS, using that credential.  We also set up a login for that same credential.  The proxy is set up as having Subsystem 'SQL Server Integration Services Package', and Principals of 'SQLAgentReaderRole', 'SQLAgentUserRole', and 'SQLAgentOperatorRole'.

After this, I created a job to run the task, simply calling the .dtsx package I created.  This job has a Type of 'SQL Server Integration Packages', and is set to run as the proxy user.

In attempting to run the package itself, from inside its path under the Integration Services Catalogs directory in Object Explorer, I can execute the .dtsx as myself and it will run to completion.

In attempting to run the job (manually clicking the 'Start Job As' option), however, it will run for about thirty seconds or so and then error out.  Checking the reports on the package reveals that the error message is as follows (exact names obscured):

`[Find file to reload Task]: Error: Access to the path '[Path\to\DB_file\directory]' is denied.  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)`

I have checked with the coworker who created the original credential; the service user it's suppose to be associated with has, as far as I can see, full permissions on the target read-in directory.

What else could be generating this 'Path Denied' error message?  Everything I'm finding online comes down to 'set the permissions correctly', but I'm not seeing what permissions we haven't gotten set.

Are there other things which can trigger this error?  Or failing that, where do I need to look for the permissions which are apparently not being set?

Comment: Should be normal file permissions.  Check the folder for its NTFS permissions, and if it is accessed through a Share check the share permissions on the target server.  Also create a local folder and copy the file there to test.

Comment: You can debug permissions by creating a simple copy bat-script that does something to that folder and run it from sql agent using the same credential.